# how to handle multiple paths inside on Route in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to handle two different route inside one `Route`, here's the code :

```
<Route exact path={['/$:username', '/$:username/:section']} render={(props)=><FullProfile {...props} me={this.props.me}/>} />
```

and inside of `FullProfile` I'll console the props. However if I enter the first path, the `username` param will be `undefined`and if I enter the second one I'll get it as is.

to clarify, say I enter `mydomain.com/$john` then the `props.match` will be :

```
params:
section: undefined
username: undefined
```

and if I enter `mydomain.com/$john/likes` then `props.match` will be:

```
params:
section: "likes"
username: "john"
```

When I entered the first path, `username` was `undefiend`, why ? as you saw I put my paths into an array so it's supposed to work fine for both cases.

Comment: which version of react-router are you on

Comment: since array type path params have only been added in react-router-dom v4.4 onwards and its works perfectly fine in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/8yo61w900l

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thank you for your effort, I've been using 4.3.1 it's because the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array of string paths are only supported from v4.4 of react-router. Update to the latest alpha version of react-router-dom to use array of string as paths

Working demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/8yo61w900l